# export gridview data to excel as downloadable link to end-users

Tags: asp.net, html, excel, gridview

I'm using this code as export to excel from gridview in local machine.....

```
   void btn_excelClick()
{
 Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;


    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "c.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);



    GridView2.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

My Question is: How should i modify my code so that the file is downloaded in server side when the end-user clicks on it, and a download link for the source file should pop up.

PS: My Comp is currently my server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing your output to the Response, write it to a file.

Ensure that the path to where you write the file is in a directory that is accessible through IIS.

```
GridView2.RenderControl(htw);
var path = Server.MapPath("~/PublicFiles/FileName");
File.WriteAllText(path, sw.ToString());
```

Now you can just write a link to the file in the response, and set the path to this newly created file.

Comment: can u just gimme me a walkthrough if possible, i'm completely a newbie to this..thanks

Comment: should the file name be given as the one which i tried to convert to excel....in my case (c.xls)...thanks

Comment: Yes, the file name should be where you want it saved.

Comment: I want the file to be stored in another directory than the root..
What should i write in the path, if for e.g, I want it to get stored in wwwroot folder of IIS....thanks

Comment: If your app is not running in a virtual directory then you can directly get the root path from `Server.MapPath("~")`. Add your file path to that to get the full path

Comment: modified my code using server.getfullpath and got to save the file in some other folder. but the dialog box still pop's up showing the contents to open, save or view the file just saved. How to avoid that, as i want to make a button a visible when this process is complete and then download. thanks

Comment: It that shows up, you have not removed the part of code where you writing the file to output... `Response.Write(sw.ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do following:

1.) To let some one download file from your server on web, you will need a folder shared to all on IIS.

2.) Simply write the response to a file in the shared folder.

3.) Now you will need an action for downloading the file. For this simply put a hyperlink on the web page and set the href property to the Web Location of the file. Whenever any user will click yhe link the file be downloaded to that persons machine.

P.S.  WebURL means  URL of your site followed by the folder location. For eg: www.example.com/Folder1/Folder2/File1.xls

Comment: can u just gimme a link for to understand these concepts. thanks

Comment: To know how to share files with IIS use this link http://www.boyce.us/windows/tipcontent.asp?ID=478